# How to check token transactions with geth

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, tokens, json-rpc, ipc

I'm new to smart contracts, my apologies if this is a wrong approach.

I want to monitor incoming (confirmed, not caring about pending) token transactions to my wallet (using geth). I found out how to check the token balance (using eth_call), but actually I want it separated as single transactions (preferably having the possibility to check certain block-ranges). I need to do this by using JSON-RPC (IPC).

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you [Get ERC-20 token transfer transaction for some address with JSON-RPC node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37585/get-erc-20-token-transfer-transaction-for-some-address-with-json-rpc-node/38504#38504)