# Get ERC-20 token transfer transaction for some address with JSON-RPC node

Tags: transactions, erc-20, json-rpc

How can I get `ERC-20` token transfer transactions for some address with `JSON-RPC` node?

**Input:**

1. Token Contract address
2. Token Contract ABI
3. Address
4. Start block
5. End block

**Output:**

1. JSON with list of token transfer transactions

Thanks!

Comment: Start with https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getlogs. Post again if you run into any specific issues.

Comment: @smarx Thanks for your answer, but I can't receive any data from the node with this command `curl --data '{"method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"fromBlock":"earliest","toBlock":"latest","address":["0xd497e2c79564a444c9e2f9e53a821790a70edf22"]}],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://[MY_ROPSTEN_NODE_IP]:8545`

Comment: The value for `address` should just be a single address, not a list. (`"address": "0xd497..."`, no brackets).

Comment: @smarx Result the same `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[],"id":1}`. Have you some code examples how to get `ERC-20` transactions from `JSON-RPC` node?

Comment: The address you're passing isn't a contract, so it doesn't have any logs.

Comment: And no, this isn't a code-writing service. If you have specific issues when you write your code, you can ask them on this site. But please don't ask others to write the code for you.

Comment: @smarx I want to receive ERC-20 tokens transfer transactions for some address, but not for the contract address. So as I see I must get all transactions for the contract and then separate them by addresses.Thank you in any case!

Comment: `eth_getLogs` can filter, so you can certainly get just the transfer events that pertain to a given account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope my solution on PHP will help somebody:

```
public static function getTransactionsERC20($nodeCode, $tokenContractAddress, $address, $fromBlock, $toBlock) {
        $nodes = Config::getSettings('nodes');
        if (!array_key_exists($nodeCode, $nodes)) {
            throw new \Exception("Invalid node code '{$nodeCode}'");
        }

        $logs = self::_request($nodes[$nodeCode], [
            'method' => "eth_getLogs",
            'params' => [[
                'fromBlock' => $fromBlock,
                'toBlock' => $toBlock,
                'address' => $tokenContractAddress,
                'topics' => [
                    null, null,
                    "0x000000000000000000000000" . substr($address, 2)
                ]
            ]],
            'id' => 1,
            'jsonrpc' => "2.0"
        ]);

        if (!array_key_exists('result', $logs) || empty($logs['result'])) {
            return [];
        }

        $txnsData = array_filter($logs['result'], function($e) {
            return ($e['type'] == "mined");
        });

        $txns = [];
        foreach ($txnsData as $txData) {
            $tx = self::_request($nodes[$nodeCode], [
                'method' => "eth_getTransactionByHash",
                'params' => [
                    $txData['transactionHash']
                ],
                'id' => 1,
                'jsonrpc' => "2.0"
            ]);

            if (!array_key_exists('result', $tx)) {
                continue;
            }

            //var_dump($tx);
            $input = $tx['result']['input'];

            $method = substr($input, 0, 10);
            $toAddress = substr($input, 10, 64);
            $amount = substr($input, 74, 64);
            if ($method !== "0xa9059cbb") { // transfer
                continue;
            }

            $txn = $tx['result'];
            $txn['action']['from'] = $txn['from'];
            $txn['action']['to'] = "0x" . substr($toAddress, 24);
            $txn['action']['value'] = $amount;
            $txns[] = $txn;
        }

        return $txns;
    }
```

Comment: in my case amount return like this "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001dcd6500"

Comment: how to convert this string to number ?

Comment: i am using web3@0.19

Comment: @KaushikMakwana you could use `hexdec()` function in PHP [http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php]